# Passing a $_GET variable from Wordpress page into external iFrame

Tags: php, html, wordpress, iframe, get

I have searched throughout all of the internets to fix this issue - I am sure this can be done! 
I am trying to pass a `$_GET` variable into an external page that is accessed through an `iframe`. 
My website is done on `Wordpress` and I have downloaded a `plugin` to use an `iframe` so that I can show a page that contains `PHP`. 
This is the way it works:

The page on `Wordpress` should have a `$_GET` parameter in its `URL` 
(like this: http://www.url.com/page/refer-a-friend/?source=CRM)

I need to access this `$_GET parameter` inside my `iframe`. The `iframe` src is a page I do not have on `Wordpress` but that is on my server (it's like an external link).

I feel like I have given all the information I can but if not please feel free to ask and I can elaborate. It's driving me crazy! Thanks.

Please note I am passing the iFrame through the shortcode. 
[iframe src="https://www.globaleye.com/external/refer.php" width="100%" height="500"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

```
[iframe src="globaleye.com/external/refer.php?YOUR_VARIABLE=true"; width="100%" height="500"]
```

if you used more than one variable pass so you use an advanced iframe plugin so it is good for you.

```
[advanced_iframe securitykey="key" url_forward_parameter="SECOND_VARIABLE" src="globaleye.com/external/refer.php?YOUR_VARIABLE=true"]
```

Comment: The iFrame is being called from a shortcode from a Wordpress page - I cannot use any javascript or php!

Comment: post your shortcode over there. then i will tell you how do you do it.

Comment: [iframe src="https://www.globaleye.com/external/refer.php" width="100%" height="500"]

Comment: `[iframe src="globaleye.com/external/refer.php?external_param=' . $_GET['source'] . '" width="100%" height="500"] `

Comment: Pretty sure I cannot pass PHP through a wordpress page. I tried that and the iFrame stopped working.

Comment: Leave all javascript code just focus on iframe tag because everything is on iframe tag.

Comment: The first shortcode is provided by a plugin - I am pretty sure the second one will not be accepted. As for the first one, What is YOUR_VARIABLE going to equal to ? I do not understand your suggestion :(

Comment: ?$a=1; it's just like this so you can easily $_GET.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122289/discussion-between-charlotteoswald-and-syed-noman).

Answer (score 0):

In your code, where you call the iFrame:

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com/some/site?external_get_param=<?php echo $_GET['source']"></iframe>
```

Comment: please post the shortcode then. there should be a way to pass the `$_GET` param

Comment: [iframe src="https://www.globaleye.com/external/refer.php" width="100%" height="500"]

Comment: `[iframe src="globaleye.com/external/refer.php?external_param=' . $_GET['source'] . '" width="100%" height="500"]`

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the plugin Advanced iFrame - which allowed me to use the parameters passed in the parent page! Amazing plugin.